# How to keep portrait launch screen on iPhone 6/6s Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a problem with ip6/6s plus about launch screen.

**Description:**

I've set portrait for Launch Screen.xib. When I rotate device iphone 5,6, the screens are running well. However, I'm running on iphone 6 plus and rotate screen. The Launch Screen is showing with landscape mode. Now,I want to keep portrait Launch screen when iPhone 6 plus rotate. [image: on iphone 5/6/6s] [image: on iphone 6/6s plus]

You will save my life. Thanks

Comment: Do you want your app to run in portrait only and always?

Comment: Yes. Almost screens in my app are running portrait. The only screen running both portrait and landscape. But Launch Screen.xib, i only want to show with portrait.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run your entire app in portrait mode only you can change these settings on your target. Just use the check boxes to select which orientations you would like to support.

ProjectName > General

[image]

Comment: if no screen needs landscape orientation then this answer will solve your problem @Cuong

Comment: I cant set as you comment. Because, almost screens in my app are running portrait. but my app has just screen is running both(portrait/landscape).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following method.

```
#define IS_IPHONE                               (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH                            ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT                           ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH                       (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH                       (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IPHONE4                                 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IPHONE5                                 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IPHONE6                                 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IPHONE6PLUS                             (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)



-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        if (IPHONE6 || IPHONE6PLUS) {
            return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Or you can use the one more method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Your solution for UIViewController. However, my problem is keeping portrait for splash screen that running first when app starting.